# Spark job FetchFailed on cluster but works on laptop

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, rdd

I have a 20GB file and a 400MB file which I'm mapping each to project 6 attributes each. I then create a K, V RDD by creating a hash with part of the attributes (first 2 letters of firstname and first 4 letters of surname).

So I now have `a: RDD[K,V]` and `b: RDD[K,V]` with a common key so I want to join them

`a.join(b).map(x=> [check commonality in the attributes]).SaveAsTextFile(fileout)`

The strange part is that I run this on HDFS on my 16GB Macbook and it works in around 16 mins. When I put it on our 3 worker node cluster with 96GB each I get repeated FetchFailed exceptions.

Can this really be down to the HDFS on my mac all being the same SSD and the absence of network IO or is there something else I can look at?

I'm using Cloudera 5.3.1 and running spark on Yarn, the executor logs have limited information I've not worked out how to adjust the logging level of executors to get more info. Any idea how to do this?

Example stack below;

```
FetchFailed(null, shuffleId=0, mapId=-1, reduceId=6, message=
    org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 0
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$1.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:386)
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$1.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:383)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:382)
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.getServerStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:178)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.BlockStoreShuffleFetcher$.fetch(BlockStoreShuffleFetcher.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleReader.read(HashShuffleReader.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:127)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.compute(CoGroupedRDD.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedValuesRDD.compute(MappedValuesRDD.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.FlatMappedValuesRDD.compute(FlatMappedValuesRDD.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.FilteredRDD.compute(FilteredRDD.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    
    )
```

Comment: Have you tried reducing the number of partitions? In your case it's analogous to reducing the number of letters taken for key, e. g. 2 for fname, 2 for lname.

Comment: I've tried a large number of partitions to reduce the amount of data being processed and a few partitions to get it done in one go. Both end up with FetchFailed exceptions

Comment: You don't need to create a hash as the key yourself. The keys get hashed anyway. It's simpler if you just use the full name that you want to match on. I have no idea why you're getting `FetchFailedException` though. Do you lose executors? Can you paste the full exception? How many partitions do you have?

Comment: Sorry, I doubt you will get a definitive answer to such a debugging question. The executor logs are linked from the Spark UI. First I would check whether you've lost any executors. You would see "lost executor" log entries in the driver logs. Also when the executor is restarted (happens automatically) it will get a new ID. So if the running executors are not numbered from 0 to N contiguously, then you know there was a restart. (The executor with the missing number was lost.)

Comment: @DanielDarabos okay, thanks. I'm pretty sure I'm losing executors because there is a lot of retrying stages. Like it starts the save text file then fails a few tasks and then falls back to the preceding stage of map. Thanks anyway